# Stop onTapGesture if Toggle is tapped

Tags: swiftui

I'm attempting to modify an existing view by adding a Toggle to a row in a subview.  The top view shows a Scrollview of rows from a database.  The rows are a subview.  Currently in the top view I use onTapGesture to trigger a sheet to appear to allow editing of a row as tapped.  Now I want to add a toggle to the row subview.  Which I've done.  But when the Toggle is tapped it also triggers the onTapGesture of the parent view.  This is undesirable behavior.  I'd only want the onTapGesture to respond if the row is tapped elsewhere from the toggle.  Is there a way to inhibit the onTapGesture the way I'm hoping?

Understanding there is code here like the toolbar and pop up views that aren't relevant to my request.  (I think)

The top view code looks like this:

```
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            VStack {
                if isSubView {
                    CategoriesHeading(isSubView: isSubView, isAdding: $isAdding)
                    Divider().background(Color.primary)
                }
                
                ScrollView {
                    ForEach (self.categories, id: \.self) { categoryRecord in
                        VStack {
                            HStack {
                                if deletingRow && categoryRecord.category_code != 99999 {
                                    Button(action: {
                                        delete(selectedRecord: categoryRecord)
                                    }, label: {
                                        Image(systemName: "minus.circle.fill")
                                            .foregroundColor(.red).imageScale(.large)
                                    }).padding(.horizontal)
                                    
                                } // END IF DELETING ROW
                                CategoriesRow(categoryCode: categoryRecord.category_code, category: categoryRecord.category, isRetired: categoryRecord.retired
                                )
                                .contentShape(Rectangle())
                                .onTapGesture {
                                    categoriesRec = categoryRecord
                                    if isSubView {
                                        dismiss()
                                    } else {
                                        if deletingRow {
                                            deletingRow.toggle()
                                        }
                                        self.showSheet.toggle()
                                    }
                                } // END OF ONTAPGESTURE
                                
                            } // END OF HSTACK
                            Divider()
                        } // END OF VSTACK
                        .frame(height: 35)
                        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                    }// END OF FOREACH
                }// END OF SCROLLVIEW
                .actionSheet(isPresented: $showSheet, content: editFindOrReassign)
                .sheet(isPresented: $whereCategoryUsed) { CategoryWhereUsedView(categoryRecord:  categoriesRec)}
            } // END OF VSTACK
            Group {
                if isAdding {
                    AddCategoriesView(isAddingCategory: $isAdding)
                        .opacity(isAdding ? 1 : 0)
                        .zIndex(isAdding ? 1 : 0)
                }
                if isEditing {
                    EditCategoriesView(isEditingCategory: $isEditing, categoryDescriptionRecord: $categoriesRec)
                        .opacity(isEditing ? 1 : 0)
                        .zIndex(isEditing ? 1 : 0)
                }
                // Show subview
                if isDeleting {
                    DeleteCategoryView(isDeleting: $isDeleting, showingDeleteConfirmationAlert: $showingDeleteConfirmationAlert)
                        .opacity(isDeleting ? 1 : 0)
                        .zIndex(isDeleting ? 1 : 0)
                }
                // Show subview
                if showingDeleteConfirmationAlert {
                    ConfirmDeleteCategoryView(isDeleting:  $isDeleting, showingDeleteConfirmationAlert: $showingDeleteConfirmationAlert,   showingFailedDeleteAlert: $showingFailedDeleteAlert, categoryToUse: categoriesRec.category_code, category: categoriesRec.category)
                        .opacity(showingDeleteConfirmationAlert ? 1 : 0)
                        .zIndex(showingDeleteConfirmationAlert ? 1 : 0)
                    
                }
                // Show subview
                if reassignThisCategory {
                    CategoryReassignView(reassignThisCategory: $reassignThisCategory, categoryToReAssign:  categoriesRec)
                        .opacity(reassignThisCategory ? 1 : 0)
                        .zIndex(reassignThisCategory ? 1 : 0)
                }
                
                if showingFailedDeleteAlert{
                    DeleteFailedView(isDeleting:  $isDeleting, showingFailedDeleteAlert: $showingFailedDeleteAlert, deleteItem: categoriesRec.category)
                        .opacity(showingFailedDeleteAlert ? 1 : 0)
                        .zIndex(showingFailedDeleteAlert ? 1 : 0)
                }
            } // END OF GROUP
            .transition(AnyTransition.scale(scale: 0.1)
                .animation(.default))
        } // END OF ZSTACK
        .navigationTitle("Categories Setup")
        .ignoresSafeArea(edges: .bottom)
        .toolbar {
            ToolBarDeleteAdd(deletingRow: deletingRow) {
                toolbarViewModel.deleteContent(deletingRow: &deletingRow)
            }
        adding: {
            toolbarViewModel.addingContent(isAdding: &isAdding, deletingRow: &deletingRow)
        }
        } // END OF TOOLBAR
        
    } // END OF BODY
```

and the subview row code looks like this:

```
struct CategoriesRow: View {
    
    var categoryCode: Int
    var category: String
    @State var isRetired: Bool
    
    var body: some View {
        
        HStack {
            Spacer()
            Text(category)
                .font(.title3)
            Spacer()
            Toggle("", isOn: $isRetired)
                .labelsHidden()
                .padding(.trailing, 30)
        }
        
    }
}
```

Comment: Having overlapping tapable areas is a very bad practice, especially accessibility wise. So =you need to think how to better define a tapable area of the parent view, instead of "inhibiting" it.

Comment: Yes, I’ve come to that conclusion and I’ve been working on an alternative way to achieve my goal.  Thanks for your comment, it’s right on point.